# Undetected ChromeDriver with Proxy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, undetected-chromedriver

When i use proxy with undetected-chromedriver-v2 I see CloudFlare bot protect screen. How can bypass cloudflare screen with proxy. I want use proxy, how can fix this?

Code:

```
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome
import time
from selenium_stealth import stealth

id="proxyid"
password="proxypw"
ip="proxyip"
port="proxyport"
def proxy_test():
        options = {
        'proxy': {
                'https': "https://"+id+":"+password+"@"+ip+":"+port,
                'https': "https://"+id+":"+password+"@"+ip+":"+port,
                'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
        }
        }

        driver = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
        
        stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )
        driver.get("https://csgocases.com/")

        time.sleep(100)

def main():
    proxy_test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```